# Processwire - PHP - if link is clicked

Tags: php

I have a button on my page that if clicked opens a modal that allows user to create a topic.
I want to implement some checks, if user if logged in allow to create IF not then forward to login page. AS testing I have made IF logged in > forward to "/" IF not then for to "/login"

My code is currently as following, which does not work. It always allows to create.

```
//Check if user is logged in before allowing to create
if (isset($_GET['create'])) { 

    //Check if current user is logged in 
    if ($user->isLoggedin()) { 

        $session->redirect("/");

    }

           //If current use not logged in redirect to login
    else {

        $session->redirect("/login"); 
    }
}
<a href="#?create" role="button" name="create" class="btn btn-success btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">
```

Comment: Check should be outside

Comment: Do you mean it always forwards to "/", or do you mean that the button to create is always visible?

Comment: if the login state is saved in php thru sessions, make an ajax request to php, check a response whether the current user is logged in or not, if logged in then, continue the dialog box, if not just dont do anything

Answer (score 1):

You have have to check session before enter into create code.

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['sess_user_id']) || (trim($_SESSION['sess_user_id']) == '')) {
header("location: login.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this for sure without knowing what you are passing in the url to this page. You could have ?create=&somethingelse=true and the isset for create would still be true.

Also, in Processwire you can use:

```
$input->get->create
```

If you can provide more information on the url that is being used to access this page, I am sure it will be easy to fix. Is it the url that is coming from the create button code at the end of your code block?

Is this code in a PW template php file, or is it a bootstrapped script?

Something else that is confusing about your code is the href line at the end - it is html? You never closed your php tags from the code above.